# download windows symbols programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, windbg

I want to programmatically download symbols from the micrsoft symbol server  (http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols). 
E.g. given the name "ntdll.dll" I want to save the .pdb into any directory.

The APIs from dbghelp.dll seems to solve this. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
But I don't know how to use them in a right way.

Does anyone did something like this before and can show me some example code?

thanks!

Comment: It will be easier to use MS-supplied utilities, such as `symchk`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503

Comment: indeed its easier. But this will be part of my own little debugger and I dont want to be dependend on extern utilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never did something exactly like *this*, but I was intrigued enough to look. Your friends are the `SymXxx` functions, within *dbghelp.dll*.

Start with `SymSetOptions` followed by `SymInitialize`.
Then, the function that does the heavy lifting of the work is [SymFindFileInPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The second arguments (SearchPath) is a semicolon-separated search path, that may include `SRV*`.

The utility that does exactly what you want (pretty much, with nothing less and nothing more) is symchk.exe. Take a look at its imports table, notice it uses no more than 9 functions from dbghelp (and no 'networking' DLL such as winhttp or the like) - so that should give you a good clue how to proceed, and which methods you should use.